# Returning a new ImmutableList that is an existing list plus an extra element

Tags: java, immutablelist

I'm using Google's ImmutableList class http://google-collections.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/ImmutableList.html

I'm looking for a method which takes an existing ImmutableList and an extra element (of the same type), and returns a *new* ImmutableList that contains the old elements plus the new one.

Perhaps I'm missing something obvious in the docs?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
public static final ImmutableList<Foo> result
   = new ImmutableList.Builder<Foo>()
       .addAll(originalList)
       .add(new Foo())
       .build();
```

Comment: But that doesn't do any structural sharing - it just creates a new list with the same elements.

Comment: Yes. But structural sharing wasn't part of the OP's question. And I don't think ImmutableList supports it.

Comment: It wasn't explicitly part of the OP's question, but he did add a tag "structural-sharing" to the question. And I agree that Guava's `ImmutableList` does not support this.

Comment: Yes, it's a pity that ImmutableList doesn't do structural-sharing, but not a requirement.  The lists have under 20 elements.

Answer (score 2):

You could do it the following way:

```
ImmutableList<YourType> newList = ImmutableList.copyOf(
    Iterables.concat(existingList, ImmutableList.of(newElement))
);
```

**Edit:** @JB Nizets solution looks more readable :)